# CircleCI uses wrong RubyVersion (it ignores gemfile)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, gemfile, circleci

During `bundle` command in CircleCI build I got error message

```
Your Ruby version is 2.2.1, but your Gemfile specified 2.2.2

bundle check --path=vendor/bundle || bundle install --path=vendor/bundle --jobs=4 --retry=3  returned exit code 18

Your Ruby version is 2.2.1, but your Gemfile specified 2.2.2 Action failed: bundle install
```

even though I have

```
ruby '2.2.2'
```

specified at the top of Gemfile. Why CircleCI ignores it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CircleCI checks for specified ruby version in these files:

1. `.rvmrc`
2. `.ruby-version`
3. `Gemfile`

in this particular order!  If it finds ruby version specified in `.rvmrc` then it will ignore `.ruby-version` and `Gemfile` and will use ruby version defined in `.rvmrc`

In my case I had `ruby-2.2.1` inside my `.ruby-version` and `ruby 2.2.2` inside `Gemfile`. It used ruby-2.2.1 evan though `Gemfile` required `2.2.2`.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this issue and it was my circle.yml file. I hadn't updated it:

```
machine:
    ruby:
        version: 2.2.2
```